# Why doesn't scp command allow wildcat star when copying files?

Tags: scp

For example, I am copying files from a remote machine to my local Mac:

```
scp -P 33 root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/*test .
```

This gives an error:

```
zsh: no matches found: root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/*test
```

But If i copy files individually, it worked:

```
scp -P 33 root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/my_test .
```

I also tried with the same command on Linux, and it worked file for using wildcat form.

Comment: Since the star has to be expanded remotely, you need to quote it so it isn't expanded locally.

Comment: To quote the whole thing 'root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/*test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `noglob` in front of `scp` to make the wildcard work.

```
noglob scp -P 33 root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/*test .
```

In case you are on zsh you can also set `alias scp='noglob scp'` in your `.zshrc`